# How to get Binarize to ignore already set background

Tags: image-processing

I have grayscale images which contain a clear foreground and background, which Binarize is easily able to split out. Then within the foreground, I want to binarize again, to find the area around the high point.

Here is an example image (modified from one of the examples in the help for `RemoveBackground`):

[image]

```
pepper = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX1jr.png"]
```

Now this image has a chili pepper, which is the brightest part, a few leaves and then an almost black background. I want to select just the chili, not the leaves too.

`RemoveBackground` will easily remove the black background and make it transparent if I wish,

```
pepper2 = RemoveBackground[pepper, Black]
```

[image]

Or I can set it to be non-transparent entirely black via:

```
pepper3 = ImageMultiply[pepper, Binarize[pepper]]
```

Having done that, I can't use `Binarize` (or `FindThreshold`) again, as it treats the background as still being there.

```
GraphicsRow[{pepper, pepper2, pepper3}]
```

[image]

How do I find the 'best' region around the point of highest intensity? If I can clip the image sufficiently that the actual background is entirely removed, Binarize will work fine and give me a nice looking region.

My actual images look something more like this:

[image]

which you can see from a 3D plot has a well-defined bump, that I wish to characterise.

```
actual = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMbiE.png"]
ListPlot3D[ImageData@actual, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't suppose you want to just use `RemoveBackground` before your binarize?

Comment: @CarlLange, `RemoveBackground` just sets the background to have an alpha channel, which `ImagePad` actually does too (when the initial image has an alpha channel, as this one has gained when I uploaded it).

Comment: Ah, hmm. I suppose `ImageCrop` with no arguments would also work.

Comment: @CarlLange, my background isn't nice and uniform, so I can't just crop it out of the picture - the foreground can go towards the edge of the image in several different directions

Comment: @KraZug you really need to formulate your problem properly --- especially posting the _right_ original image you are working and the result you seeking.

Comment: You can use `Binarize[img, you_dezired_threshold]`. The value of the threshold can be determined for a sub-image obtained by `FindThreshold@ImageTake[img,{col1,col2},{row1,row2}]`. Choosing the area around the maximum of intensity, one can find the right binarization.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov, I'll try and get an example image that I can use, I can't use my actual data.

Comment: If the background is always black, you can probably clip the image by doing something like `Binarize[i, {0.0000000000000001, 1}]` and then running `Binarize`/`FindThreshold` on the result.

Comment: @CarlLange, I have an image that has a clear foreground/background, which Binarize easily finds. Within the foreground, I'm then looking to further pinpoint the area around the brightest region. Working on editing the question now.

Comment: I don't have time to try this right now, so this is only a comment: `FindThreshold` only uses the histogram, it ignores the spatial structure of the image. So if you could extract all "valid" pixels from your source image (e.g. using `Pick`) to a list and put that in a new image, then `FindThreshold[Image[{validPixels}]]` should happily calculate a threshold for these pixels. You can then pass that threshold to `Binarize`

Comment: Have a look at `MorphologicalBinarize[pepper, {0.8, 0.9}]` which does almost what you want.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell, yes, but I don't want to have to specify the thresholds myself, I want to use the automated methods for finding the cutoffs.

Comment: The real problem here is growing the above-threshold region(s) in a connected way, rather than choosing the thresholds. `MorphologicalBinarize` is not the same as `Binarize`, because it uses neighbourhood connectivity to grow the above-threshold region(s).